# Platform declaration clash: The following declarations have the same JVM signature ( (ILjava/util/List;)V):

Tags: kotlin, parameters, constructor

Two Constructor in one data class, both Constructor parameter is same. parametr is different Arraylist. Arraylist key and value is different.

it's give Error :

```
Platform declaration clash: The following declarations have the same JVM signature ( (ILjava/util/List;)V): 
public constructor DataItem(viewType: Int, detailList: List<Detail>) defined in com.example.productdeatail.DataItem
public constructor DataItem(viewType: Int, recyclerItemList: List<RecyclerItem>) defined in com.example.productdeatail.DataItem
```

so, how to define same parameter in constructor?

```
data class DataItem(val viewType : Int){

    var recyclerItemList : List<RecyclerItem>? = null

    var detailList : List<Detail>? = null
    constructor(viewType: Int, recyclerItemList : List<RecyclerItem>): this(viewType){
        this.recyclerItemList = recyclerItemList
    }

    constructor(viewType: Int, detailList: List<Detail>) : this(viewType){
        this.detailList = detailList
    }

  

}
data class RecyclerItem(val id : Int, val image : String)

data class DetailList(val viewType: Int){
    var detailList : List<Detail>? = null
    constructor(viewType: Int, detailList: List<Detail>) : this(viewType){
        this.detailList = detailList
    }
}
data class Detail(
    val image : Int,
    val key : String,
    val value : String)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this.

Generics disappear at compile-time, leaving you with two constructor with the same signature : *DetailItem(Int, List)*.

What you can do is:

1. define a single constructor with default arguments:

```kotlin
data class DataItem(val viewType: Int, 
                    var detailList: List<Detail>? = null,
                    var recyclerItemList: List<RecyclerItem>? = null)
```

This allow you to build an item like:

```kotlin
val item = DataItem(2)
```

or

```kotlin
val item = DataItem(2, detailList=listOf(Detail(...), ...))
```

or

```kotlin
val item = DataItem(2, recyclerItemList=listOf(RecyclerItem(...), ...))
```

2. If your aim is to create an item with either details or recyclers, but not both, I suggest a different approach: using sealed type hierarchy, like follow:

```kotlin
sealed interface DataItems<T> {
    val viewType: Int
}

data class RecyclerItems(
    override val viewType: Int,
    val items: List<RecyclerItem>
) : DataItems

data class DetailItems(
    override val viewType: Int,
    val items: List<Detail>
) : DataItems
```

You can then define an item like this:

```kotlin
val item : DataItem = RecyclerItems(2, emptyList())
```

and check if it contain details or recyclers like that:

```kotlin
when (item) {
    is RecyclerItems -> item.items.forEach {
        /* here, "it" is a RecyclerItem */ 
    }
    is DetailItems -> item.items.forEach {
        /* here, "it" is a Detail object */
    }
```

or

```kotlin
sealed interface DataItems<T> {
    val viewType: Int
    val items: List<T>
}

data class RecyclerItems(
    override val viewType: Int,
    override val items: List<RecyclerItem>
) : DataItems<RecyclerItem>

data class DetailItems(
    override val viewType: Int,
    override val items: List<Detail>
) : DataItems<Detail>
```

that you can use like so:

```kotlin
val items : DataItems<Detail> = DetailItems(1, emptyList())
```